# create safe sender list based on domains of email recipients in Exchange

Tags: exchange, spam

We're moving from Google Postini to Symantec Cloud as a spam filter.

In Postini we've managed to collect a total number of about 3400 domains added over the years to our safe sender list. But Symantec supports only about 3000 or so.

Now I can't just determine which ones to delete, so I was wondering whether it would be easier to start from another basis and ignore the old list.

I was thinking about collecting all domains from the email addresses that all of us mailed to in the last two years. That would be a good starting point I suppose. But is it possible, to get such a list from Exchange 2007 somehow? It would be even better if the list would mention the number of mails we sent to the domains, so I can order them accordingly.

But other suggestions are welcome too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each hosted mail gateway varies on what it will and won't consider spam.  As such, any time I've ever implemented a switch like this I will only grab well known domains we do B2B or B2C with on a regular basis and bring that over as whitelisting.

The rest I let the new system determine on its own and then start tweaking from there.

I've found 2 things to be true by doing this:

1. The domains we had whitelisted over the years we never received anything business worthy after the date/time of whitelisting them.
2. The internal users that were requesting/requiring the domain whitelist either no longer worked there or couldn't remember why they requested it to begin with.

**It's also a much better practice to whitelist at the actual email address level and not the entire domain, and if possible whitelist on both sender email and recipient email (end-user whitelisting).**

So you might be doing your company a better service by not trying to bring over 3,000 domains for whitelisting, and Symantec would probably say "hey you pay us to filter spam, let us at least show you whether or not what you are paying for works before manually controlling everything."

Comment: I agree with what you suggest, and that's what I meant mostly. I edited my question accordingly. I want to ignore the old list and start a new one with all recipient addresses or domains that we sent mails to the last two years. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Your Exchange logs typically won't go back that far, and even then you are talking about parsing the logs with some programming external to Exchange to get aggregate counts, etc.  If you didn't already have a 3rd party logging tool in place, I'm not certain you can get what you are after, but maybe another expert would know.

Comment: Do you know how to get a list of all email addresses that our company sent mails to, as much as the Exchange logs allow? I can do the processing and aggregation, no problem. I just don't know how to get such a list... Thanks!

Comment: You would need to parse the SMTP logs.  There are 3rd party tools over on msexchange.org that cost, but you can get LogParser and follow the guides here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2007/11/12/3404342.aspx